# Unable to update record in SQLite

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, uwp, sql-update

I have two tables. I am attempting to update records that match the criteria.
While one of the two gets updated, the other does not.
Here is the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    currentProduct = e.Parameter as Product;

    NameBox.Text = currentProduct.Name;

    ReadAllProductsList dbproduct = new ReadAllProductsList();
    DB_ProductList = dbproduct.GetAllProducts();
    var productQuery = DB_ProductList.Where(Product => Product.Name == currentProduct.Name.Trim());
    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
    productList = productQuery.ToList();
}
```

Here is the Update Product method:

```
private async void UpdateProduct_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    currentProduct.Name = NameBox.Text;

    Db_Helper.UpdateDetails(currentProduct);//Update selected DB product Id

    List<Product2> product2List = new List<Product2>();
    ReadAllProduct2List dbproduct2list = new ReadAllProduct2List();
    DB_Product2 = dbproduct2list.GetAllProduct2();
    product2List = DB_Product2.Where(Product2 => Product2.ProductId == NameBox.Text.ToString()).ToList();


    for (int i = 0; i < product2List.Count -1; i++)
    {
        product2List[i].ProductId = NameBox.Text;
        Db_Helper.UpdateProduct2Details(product2List[i]);
    }

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ProductsPage));
}
```

The first update works, first table gets the product updated.
The second update doesnt work, as if the list of second type was empty.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

And here is the DB_Helper code:

```
public void UpdateDetails(Product ObjProduct)
{
    using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
    {

        var existingproduct = conn.Query<Product>("select * from Product where Id =" + ObjProduct.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (existingproduct != null)
        {

            conn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                conn.Update(ObjProduct);
            });
        }

    }
}
```

and `DB_Helper`:

```
DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
```

WHile first table can contain only one Product, the second list can contain multiple rows of than Product's name.That is why I iterate through the list to update Product2 table.

I have tested the list, and it is not empty.

Comment: what is Db_Helper?

Comment: it is a class that performs update. I will include the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I managed to solve the problem by substituting the for loop with the foreach loop.

instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < product2List.Count -1; i++)
                    {
                        product2List[i].ProductId = NameBox.Text;
                        Db_Helper.UpdateProduct2Details(product2List[i]);

                    }
```

I wrote:

```
 foreach (product in product2List)
{
product.ProductId = NameBox.Text;
Db_Helper.UpdateProduct2Details(product);
```

I am not sure why the for loop didn't work in first place.